# Git does not auto commit after pull , There is no merge conflicts

Tags: git, macos

Git does not auto commit after pull.There is no merge conflicts.

I need to commit each time after pull.

I know that there is a `--no-commit` flag, but I don't use it, my .gitconfig file is empty.

This problem does not happen if there Fast-forward merge during pull

I am doing

```
git pull
```

output

```
Merge branch 'master' of https://github.com/xxx/xx

 #Please enter a commit message to explain why this merge is necessary,
 #especially if it merges an updated upstream into a topic branch.

 #Lines starting with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts
 #the commit.
```

Can someone help ?

Comment: Please show your _actual command-line command_. Or, if you are using some GUI like Xcode or Sourcetree, say so.

Comment: I am doing git pull

Comment: If it does not "auto commit", what does it do instead? Please show the console output of the command.

Comment: You need to provide full example.... "Then "git pull" will fetch and replay the changes from the remote master branch since it diverged from the local master (i.e., E) until its current commit (C) on top of master and record the result in a new commit along with the names of the two parent commits and a log message from the userdescribing the changes." - from here https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull

Comment: @demas done please check

Comment: Also show what `git config --get-regexp 'merge|pull'` says, please. We don't necessarily believe you about the config.

Comment: Ok well what you are seeing is correct behaviour. If there is a fast forward, it just fast forwards. If there is not, there is a commit and you must write a commit message. That is how merge works, and pull involves merge. What's the problem?

Comment: @VaheHarutyunyan, `git` ask you to merge changes: local and remote. You don't have conflicts, but you still need to make `merge`. In your case you need simply save opened file and close the editor

Comment: in my Windows OS in it didn't ask anything just autocomit, is this a really expected default behevor ?

Comment: @matt branch.master.merge refs/heads/master

Answer (score 4):

What you are seeing is correct and expected behavior. If it is possible to fast-forward, there is no merge so there is no commit. Otherwise, there *is* a commit, and you are offered a chance to edit the commit message.

If you don't want a chance to edit the commit message after a pull, say

```
git pull --no-edit
```

If you don't want to say that every time, you can set the `mergeOptions` for this branch.

However, I cannot recommend any of that; pausing to edit the merge and study its effects is *good*, not bad. In fact, I cannot recommend using `git pull` at all; you should `git fetch`, study the result, and then do an explicit `merge` as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

As I see `git` ask you to merge changes: local and remote. You don't have conflicts, but you still need to make [merge](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge). In your case you need simply save opened file and close the editor.

If you want you can change to commit message before the saving the file and close the editor.

If you want to avoid this merge commit, you need to use `fast-forward` updates strategy ([docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull)).

> Note that fast-forward updates do not create a merge commit

For me, fast-forward merging is fine for short-lived branches, but in a more complex history, non-fast-forward merging makes the history easier to understand.

Comment: is there a way to avoid it , just auto commit with default message ? in windows I didn't have this problem

Comment: @VaheHarutyunyan `git commit` will auto-generate a message for merge commits that says something like "merged branch X into branch Y" and then lists the conflicts if any.

Comment: @VaheHarutyunyan `fast-forward` - the only option to avoid this merge commit

Comment: or `git pull --rebase`